# If I write a text in an acitvity it saves the text in all acitvities, im using sharedpreference how can I fix this?

Tags: java, json, android-studio, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I want to write a text in an acitivity and save it in this acitivity only and not in ALL activities.
How can I do this ?

This is my code for the dinneracitivity:

et = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);;
        savebt = findViewById(R.id.save_btn);

```
    init();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getIntExtra("position",  -1) != -1) {
        try {
            String s = et.getText().toString();
            if(!preferences.getString("saved", "").equals(""))
                savedata = new JSONObject(preferences.getString("saved", ""));
            et.setText(savedata.getString("saved" + intent.getIntExtra("position", 0)));
            s = savedata.getString("saved" + intent.getIntExtra("position", 0));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    savebt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String s = et.getText().toString();
            if (!s.equals("")) {
                try {
                    if (!preferences.getString("saved", "").equals(""))
                        savedata = new JSONObject(preferences.getString("saved", ""));
                    savedata.put("saved" + savedata.length(), s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("testing", savedata + "");
                editor.putString("saved", savedata.toString());
                editor.apply();
                et.setText("");
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(DinnerActivity.this, Dinner2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        }
    });

}

private void init() {
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("text", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    et = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    savebt = findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.save) {
        if (preferences.getString("saved", "").equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DinnerActivity.this, Dinner2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

This is my code for the dinner2acitivity:

recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

```
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("text", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Log.d("Testing", preferences.getString("saved", ""));
    try {
        saved = new JSONObject(preferences.getString("saved", ""));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Dinner2Activity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter());

}

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.Holder> {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Adapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(Dinner2Activity.this).inflate(R.layout.row_item,viewGroup, false);
        Holder holder = new Holder(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = recyclerView.getChildPosition(view);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Dinner2Activity.this, DinnerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.Holder holder, int position) {
        try {
            holder.textView.setText(saved.getString("saved" + position));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return saved.length();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        }
    }
```

Comment: add your code, therefore, others can help easily

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem correctly, it's happening because you're using the same name in each `getSharedPreferences()` call – `"text"`. If you don't want both Activities modifying the same preferences, you can use different names in each. However, there is also the `getPreferences()` method, which basically does exactly that for you already. The `SharedPreferences` returned from `getPreferences()` will be specific to the given `Activity`, so the changes you make in one will not affect the other.